# Dusk SQLite database not found

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-dusk

I'm getting this error:

> Database (homestead) does not exist.

When I try this simple Dusk test:

```
class ShowArticleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test */
    public function it_shows_all_articles()
    {
        Article::create([
            'title' => 'My First Article',
            'body'  => 'Some body text.'
        ]);

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/articles')
                    ->assertSee('My First Article');
        });
    }
}
```

I can see in the stack trace that the error comes from the controller method that handles the `/articles` request, which looks like this:

```
public function all()
{
    Article::all();
}
```

So it seems that the database is accessible by the test itself but not by the controller.

The `.env.dusk.local` file looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

The `homestead` file is being created in my project root folder. The file is found inside the virtual machine too and the permissions looks like this:

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant

Tried setting `DATABASE` to `database/testing.sqlite` in `.env.dusk.local`. The file is created once Dusk starts but the error still says that it can't find the `database/testing.sqlite` database.

> Database (database/testing.sqlite) does not exist.

The database file can be accessed using the `sqlite3` CLI and I can query for records without problem.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and Homestead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs inside `config/database.php`, around here:

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
]
```

Because `DB_DATABASE` inside `.env.dusk.local` is defined as `homestead`, the configuration value for `database.connections.sqlite.database` ends up just the same: `homestead`.

The actual value should be the full path to the file, which can be obtained with the `database_path()` helper. So, by simple moving `database_path()` out of the `env()` call:

```
'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE', 'database.sqlite'))
```

The value for `database.connections.sqlite.database` becomes the full path to the database file and everything seems to be working.

Comment: Very strange that almost 5 years later the Laravel devs have left this written in the way that it is.